# Why is find() not returning correct value?

Tags: javascript, html, find, addeventlistener

I´m trying that when a value that is not in the array is introduced, it shows in the screen. So, when the find method doesn´t return undefined, it shows the value that has been introduced. But I don´t know why, it always return undefined.

Code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="number">

    <script>
      var number = document.getElementById("number");

      const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 98, 44];

      var found = array1.find(element => element == number.value);

      number.addEventListener("input", function(){
        if(found == undefined){
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number.value;
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take the **actual** value from input in the event function as well as the `find` method. Otherwise you get the initial value from the input and the result of a find which does not match later inputs.

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), because you have just numbers in the array. If you would have object and need one, `find` would work better here, because you get a different result than a simple number.

A word to [Equality operator `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality). This operator should be avoided, because it changes the type fo comparing with another value. Instead use [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity), which checks the type and value.

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 98, 44];

number.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number"),
        found = array1.some(element => element == number.value);

    if (found) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'found';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'not found: ' + number.value;
    }
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="number">
```

For a smarter approach take [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)` as check with a value as number as parameter.

```js
const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 98, 44];

number.addEventListener("input", function() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;

    if (array1.includes(+number)) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'found';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'not found: ' + number;
    }
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="number">
```

Comment: I suggest not to use `==` and not to compare with `undefined` in this case

Answer (score 0):

find method should be invoked every time you change input value.
Otherwise it will be invoked once and then every time events fires nothing is calculated. So you need to put your find method inside of your event listener

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<input type="text" id="number">

<script>
    number.addEventListener("input", function () {
        var number = document.getElementById("number");
        const array1 = [5, 12, 8, 98, 44];
        var found = array1.find(element => element == number.value);
        if (found == undefined) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number.value;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i modified it a bit, you were assigning a value of number on page load. at that time we dont have any value to text box. you need to recalculate it everytime the event is triggered